# Firebase Crashlytics in iOS application not working

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I am using firebase Crashlytics in my iPad application. I did all the necessary configuration required for firebase, But on firebase Crashlytics console not show mu application.
[image]

[image]

my firebase Crashlytics console show attached snap state.
Please let me know if anyone know the reason.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you create app in fabric ?

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61096218/3794462

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue for days now and found the following solution to work for me.

In the Firebase console I navigated to my project and set the Appstore ID and App Prefix. I didn't have the fields populated before. 
[image]

Getting the App Store ID and Prefix:

In the Apple developer console, go to Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles -> App ID's under Identifiers on the left tab -> Your project. The info you need will be shown at the top.

[image]

I then re downloaded the Google-Service-Info.Plist file from the console and replaced the old one in XCode

The crashlytics tab in the Firebase console populated after I forced a crash. Did not need to do anything with Fabric.

Hope it helps